# Large discrepancy in quantmod "getSymbols" data vs. online yahoo data

Tags: yahoo, quantmod

Using:

> getSymbols("LMT")

I get the [the following returns data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CRjAs.png)

As can be seen the Adj. price is very different to closing. Going to yahoo you also see different results:

[Here the Adj. prtice is $77 on the 9tnh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Usbwx.png) vs $60 for the getSymobls data

Any Idea why the $17 difference or how to correct it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yahoo is just broken in some cases. Sometimes, what is displayed on their web page differs from what their API returns. If you click on the "download data link", you will see that what the Yahoo API returns and that it matches the quantmod results. 
http://chart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=LMT&a=5&b=1&c=2010&d=5&e=30&f=2010&g=d&ignore=.csv

In this particular case, the API data seems to make more sense. If you add up the dividends (which yahoo adjust for, along with splits), you get the adjusted price. You can get the dividends with `getDividends("LMT", src="yahoo", auto.assign = FALSE)`

I have seen these internal discrepancies cropping up more and more frequently with Yahoo. Caveat emptor

Answer (score 0):

I just found the same problem while looking into GSPC but both results website's and the API's disagree with my own extraction using this:

getSymbols('GSPC',src='yahoo',return.class = 'xts',from = Sys.Date()-10,auto.assign=FALSE,to = Sys.Date())

Comment: Is this a new question or an answer to the question?

Comment: This is an answer that adds to the prior response. The trouble with yahoo/finance is a bit more complex.

There are instaces when quantmod and yahoo's historical data differ.